# How could a boost::asio::io_service running on 1 thread wake up awaiting condition

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

Thanks for you reply Sam Miller, but i need to implement it on windows.

Look at this example o wrote:

```
boost::mutex mut;
boost::condition_variable cond;

boost::asio::io_service io_service;

boost::asio::deadline_timer t(io_service);

void test_func()
{
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lk(mut);
    cond.notify_all();
}

void cancel_test_func()
{
    boost::unique_lock< boost::mutex > lk(mut);
    auto canceled_timers = t.cancel();
    cond.wait(lk);
    printf("Canceled...%u.", canceled_timers);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  try
  {
    t.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(5));
    t.async_wait(boost::bind(&test_func));

    io_service.post(boost::bind(cancel_test_func));

    boost::thread_group tg;
    tg.create_thread( boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_service) );
    //tg.create_thread( boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_service) );

    getchar();
  }
  catch (std::exception& e)
  {
    std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

To make this example works(cancel the timer) i need to uncomment the second thread creation. With only one thread, i never receive notification.
The question is: is this behavior normal?

Comment: `cond.wait` unlocks the mutex,  `io_service` thread enters `timeout_func` due to `timer.cancel()`, and notifies the `cond` that waits in the "main" thread - no infinite wait.

Comment: But how could the same thread enters `timeout_func` and wait on condition? To enter into `timeout_func` it should interrupt the wait, go to callback, call `notify_one` then come to back to condition's `wait`

Comment: It's not the same thread, these are two different threads: thread A sets-up the timer, creates thread B and passes to it `io_service::run` function, then immediately cancels the timer, and waits on `cond`. As a result of timer cancellation, thread B invokes the completion handler, i.e. enters `timeout_function`, and notifies `cond`.

Comment: Ok now i understand, my example works because i have 2 threads, the main thread and the other one. Anyway i just realized when we use boost's io_service with always have at least 2 threads, the main and the other which makes io_service::run.
Ok thanks.

Comment: Sure, you create an addition thread in the following line: `boost::thread t( boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io) );`. Whether you have to have a separate thread for io_service::run or not - is a matter of design. See the very first Asio example, it has no additional threads: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/allocation/server.cpp

Comment: So the conclusion is: if we wish to have `boost::condition_variable` waiting for some event, we need at least 2 threads one for waiting and the second one for generate that event, right? Because in the example you gave me, there are only async callbacks each of them are executed sequentially by boost's `io_service`.

Comment: Of course, condvars, as well as other synchronization objects, imply multithreaded environment.

Comment: Ok, thanks you, i don't know how to mark current post as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A condition variable is a synchronous concept, it doesn't integrate well with an event loop like an `io_service`. If you want asynchronous events on Linux, look at [`eventfd(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/eventfd.2.html) with with `EFD_SEMAPHORE` flag for semaphore semantics. I'm not sure if there's an analogous interface on other platforms